# PHP Sessions , Timeout and tracking

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a front-end driven application for one of my clients . This application has a concept of 'Start Sales Session' which is logically different than the standard sessions but technically the same .

On session start , the session start time is saved in the database and it should automatically expire after 6 hours .

The above is fine when the user is logged in and using the application on the browser, so i can check the difference between current time and session start time and do the needful .

I want to know if there is a way to expire the session automatically after 6 hours in the database without the need for the user to be online or using the app on the browser .

NOTE : Database is on Mysql .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Cron Job sounds useful for you.

Comment: Cron job is fine , but there will be a minimum of 1000 users using the app at the same time , i am not even exaggerating .  So the question is , how often do i set the cron job to run and when would be the ideal time for the cronjob to interfere with the database ? Since it is a pretty heavy application in terms of the data .

Comment: 1000 entries is very little for a MySQL server. Best time to execute the cron job would be the most idle time of the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this is a Cron Job. You can write a PHP script that queries the database for any open sessions that are older than 6 hours, and then to close them. You then set up a Cron Job in your website control panel that calls the script once every so often. Once per 10 minutes should be more than sufficient for your requirements.

Comment: i think its better to just hard code an expiration into the session via php. no need for cron jobs

Answer (score -1):

You could set a [session max-lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) in your php configuration

`session.gc_maxlifetime 21600`

but if you insist on using a database you should look into [cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) who call upon a script that can check the age and delete sessions.